# How does .p8 key files work in work with Firebase in Production?

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I'm planning to  use test flight for my app but I was confused with how the new .p8 file works with production apps.

In the developer portal at Apple, my production is still configurable for notifications. If I were to configure it, it would require me to go through the certificate generating process. Do I still do it? Even if I do not need to for Firebase?

I would love for anybody to clarify the whole Production set up process for Push Notifications with the new .p8 file system. (preferably with Firebase)

Answer (score 1):

In Developer portal just configure and download you Push Service Certificate against your App id for production also.
.p8 is a Apple Auth-key file which you can create from Apple Developer Portal.

[image]

After this you need to put that key in FireBase App settings

[image]